# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined react-dom.production.min.js:134 at Vg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server, cdn

My server went suddenly blank and i got following error message in browser console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined react-dom.production.min.js:134 at Vg...

What can be the issue? Something wrong with the react CDN server`?

My script in the html is:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

In development mode the message is (from my development enviroment):

(index):1 Access to script at 'https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.development.js' (redirected from 'https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js') from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.development.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
App.js:63 Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined
    at App.js:63

My react components are translated from jsx to js with Babel web page. Presets: es2015, stage-2

I got the main application up by dropping "crossorigin" from the script. But it works only in development mode, not in production mode.Server is up but slow. And it shows

[Violation] 'react-invokeguardedcallback' handler took 262ms react-dom.development.js:128

Headers in production mode

```
Request URL: https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 104.16.126.175:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: public, max-age=31536000
cf-cache-status: HIT
cf-ray: 4a4e1438e86e5af7-HEL
content-encoding: br
content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
date: Wed, 06 Feb 2019 13:49:15 GMT
etag: W/"1a24b-tnTtN6dcAkNhpzBK8ZBEsa24AAw"
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
last-modified: Sat, 26 Oct 1985 08:15:00 GMT
server: cloudflare
status: 200
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-cloud-trace-context: 7ef73148e43be758d63b9525cae9fe1c
x-content-type-options: nosniff
:authority: unpkg.com
:method: GET
:path: /react-dom@16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: fi-FI,fi;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
origin: https://www.suomiverkko.online
referer: https://www.suomiverkko.online/
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 OPR/57.0.3098.106
```

Comment: nothing wrong with react cdn, there is some problem in your react code. Somewhere in your code you are trying to read property `current` of some object, but that object is undefined. You can look at traceback of error in development mode to figure out where exactly the error happened.

Comment: It has worked already 1 year now. Why this error now?

Comment: I guess you fetch data in your react app from some api. Maybe there was some problem fetching the data, or maybe it didn't sent the data your react app was expecting. Try refreshing the page and the error keeps happening, try visiting that page in development mode to see detailed error. If you are already in development mode you should have a detailed traceback of error in your console. Copy paste that whole thing in your question. If this error was just a one time thing and now your website it working fine, you can stop worrying about it too much.

Comment: Something to do header Access-Control-Allow-Origin.. (added to question). Not one time seems, server seems blank still

Comment: I got main the appilcation up by dropping "crossorigin" from the script. But it works only in development mode, not in production mode.Server is up but slow.

Comment: maybe a temporary problem  with the cdn because right now I can see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header on every react cdn, both development and production. Also I would suggest downloading the min.js and serving it on your own server instead of using cdn

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Vaibhav.

Answer (score 2):

It started working when i load these files from my own server. Obviously the issue was some sort of network issue somewhere.